# Unix timestamp of the next occurrence of 4pm, 5:20pm, etc

Tags: php, datetime, time

Any idea in PHP how to get a unix timestamp of the next occurring specified hour and minute?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
$nextTime = mktime(16, 0, 0);
if($nextTime < time()){
    $nextTime += 86400;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `strtotime("4pm")` will give you the time for today at 4pm. If it's already past 4pm, you can just add `60*60*24` to the given timestamp

```
// Example blatantly copied from AndrewR, but it uses strtotime   
$nextfourpm = strtotime("4pm");    
if ($nextfourpm < time()) {
  $nextfourpm += 60*60*24;
}
```

Comment: I would have to say `mktime` is much faster, no parsing of anything just some integer multiplication/addition. It was just the first thing that came to my head. I would use `mktime`.

Comment: Thanks Juan - I'm going to go with AndrewR's, but up voted yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now is 15:20

You want tomorrow at 16:22

BEST way for you is to create function with posting hour+ and minutes+ you want to go beyond - pure difference in time). By doing this way PHP cannot make any mistakes. And PHP can make mistakes while working with dates and stuff.

```
//stuff to post..
$hour = 25;
$minute = 2;

           function makemydate($hour,$minute)
           {
              if($hour > 0) 
              { 
              $hour = ($hour*3600); 
              }

              if($minute > 0) 
              { 
              $minute = ($minute*60);
              }

            $add = ($hour+$minute);
            $now = time();

            $unixtimestamp = ($now+$add);
            return $unixtimestamp;
           }

    echo makemydate;
```

There you go its a unix timestamp.. You need to specify time whatsoever :P